# Mix text with components in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way I can shorten this?

```
const visitInfo = (date, guide, attendee) => {
  return (
    <>
      {(date || guide) && ' The tour was performed'}
      {date && ' at '}
      {date && <TimeFormat>{date}</TimeFormat>}
      {date && ' on '}
      {date && <DateFormat}>{date}</DateFormat>}
      {guide && ` by ${guide}`}
      {attendee && ` and was attended by ${attendee}`}.
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: ...did you *try* anything? It feels like `date &&` could stand to be factored out if nothing else.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I spent long time to figure out to avoid the `date &&` repetition but couldn't find another solution than the one above and that's why I have posted the question. Does this look like I haven't tried anything?

Comment: You don't *mention* trying any other things, that's all we can go on. Also it doesn't seem very conventional; is visitInfo supposed to be a function-based component? Do DateFormat and TimeFormat really take the date as a *child*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to render multiple React components in the React.render() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577886/is-there-a-way-to-render-multiple-react-components-in-the-react-render-functio)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your feedback, much appreciated, I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text and other elements both count as children of an element, so you can wrap them in a fragment too, letting you factor out the repetition of `date &&`:

```
const visitInfo = (date, guide, attendee) => {
  return (
    <>
      {(date || guide) && ' The tour was performed'}
      {date && (
        <> at <TimeFormat>{date}</TimeFormat> on <DateFormat>{date}</DateFormat></>
      )}
      {guide && ` by ${guide}`}
      {attendee && ` and was attended by ${attendee}`}.
    </>
  );
}
```

The formatter here seems unhappy, but it works fine in e.g. [Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAbgSwgqBJMAzEMC8MAUAJgIZQCmANDAOYCuChlMp5YjZAlLgHwwDeAKBgwATmSi0RYAkOEwAPN1lz-RUmRgAfTTXqMuAMgMwA5DAAqACw1QQkmAHdiEGAAcyIrCIC2ZQiYBfZTk-EnIYIxkVFUVmWHlzBF8AMRAfUm5Q9QD5AHpElLTvDJhwBQARdVT0qEywshzcyvJq4tq8pWiYDiCuvjoGDUiAAxgAIwBPGAASfr0G4d7ovhYyNjIh41HiNkdnONZGQnGp2dX1hYCAOmCO2Q4AbgEgoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Ctypescript%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.5&externalPlugins=).

Answer (score 0):

```
const visitInfo = (date, guide, attendee) => {
  return (
    <>
      {(date || guide) && ' The tour was performed'}
      {date && ` at ${<TimeFormat>{date}</TimeFormat>} on ${<DateFormat>{date}</DateFormat>}`}
      {guide && ` by ${guide}`}
      {attendee && ` and was attended by ${attendee}`}.
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error in your console?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the typo I had. Try now using the above code.

Comment: Didn't notice:) Thanks!

Comment: The components are being rendered as `[object Object]` i.e. `The tour was performed at [object Object] on [object Object]`

Comment: Looks like TimeFormat and DateFormat returns objects. Can you try       {date && ` at ${(<TimeFormat>{date}</TimeFormat>).toString()} on ${(<DateFormat>{date}</DateFormat>).toString()}`}?

Comment: Looks like your dateFormat component returns a date object. Do you use moment in your codebase?

Comment: @a2441918 that's just *not* how you render components

Comment: @a2441918 yes, my  dateFormat component returns a date object, I'm not using moment.